# Creating custom ACL by IP for Cloud Object Storage (S3)

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am looking for a way to set a custom ACL policy on one of my Cloud Object Storage (S3) buckets but all the examples I see at https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-api-reference only show how to restrict by username. Essentially I would like to make my bucket private only unless the request is coming from a specific IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, access control is pretty coarse at the moment and is only capable of granting and restricting access to other object storage instances.  IP whitelisting is a priority for us and is the roadmap but is not currently supported. Granular access control via policies will be available later this year.